# Vuejs TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use this `product` data:

```js
data() {
    return {
        sitename: 'Vue.js Pet Depot',
        product: {
            id: 1001,
            title: 'Cat Food, 251lb bag',
            description: 'A 25 pound bag of <em>irresistible</em>,' +
            'organic goodness for your cat.',
            price: 2000,
            image: require('./assets/images/product-fullsize.jpg'),
        },
        cart: [],
    }
},
```

With this method:

```js
methods: {
    addToCart: () => {
        console.log(this.product.title + ' was added to cart');
        // this.cart.push(this.product.id)
    }
}
```

This is my template:

```html
<button class="default" v-on:click="addToCart">
    Add to cart
</button>
```

Getting another `Runtime Error`

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of
> undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code once

```
methods: {
            addToCart: function() {
                console.log(this.product.title + ' was added to cart');
                // this.cart.push(this.product.id)
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you use arrow function, this keyword inside the function refers to the function scope. this keyword inside the arrow function was not referring to the component and you were unable to access them using this keyword

Comment: @Sowmydhar Thank you very much!